# css menu animation nothing happens

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make a simple menu for my website. It's supposed to be that the menu boxes become longer when hovered over. I tried putting the end-result in my .item:hover, which worked, I have the color setting in my hover to check if it sees me. However, the animation does nothing, which bothers me. Could anyone explain what I could do better.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ITEMHOVER {
 0% { width: 17vw; }
 5% { width: 16vw; }
 100% { width: 22vw; }
}
@-moz-keyframes ITEMHOVER {
 0% { width: 17vw; }
 5% { width: 16vw; }
 100% { width: 22vw; }
}
@-o-keyframes ITEMHOVER {
 0% { width: 17vw; }
 5% { width: 16vw; }
 100% { width: 22vw; }
}
@keyframes ITEMHOVER {
 0% { width: 17vw; }
 5% { width: 16vw; }
 100% { width: 22vw; }
}

.item:hover {
 -webkit-animation: itemHover 2s;
 -moz-animation: itemHover 2s;
 -o-animation: itemHover 2s;
 animation: itemHover 2s;
 color: #000000;
}
```

Added snippet because the website refused to post my code because he's spacebar-blind.

Edit: Changed the "width: value;" to "transform: schaleX(value);". Didn't work.

Edit2: jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddrekkf9/ someone requested.

Comment: can you put it in jsfiddle so we can try?

Comment: done
#atleast15charcters

Answer (score 1):

It's because the animation name is case sensitive, and also you have to prefix the transforms in your animation. If you do this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes ITEMHOVER {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scaleX(1); }
  25% { -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.90); }
  75% { -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.25); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.20); }
}
@-moz-keyframes ITEMHOVER {
  0% { -moz-transform: scaleX(1); }
  25% { -moz-transform: scaleX(0.90); }
  75% { -moz-transform: scaleX(1.25); }
  100% { -moz-transform: scaleX(1.20); }
}
@-o-keyframes ITEMHOVER {
  0% { -o-transform: scaleX(1); }
  25% { -o-transform: scaleX(0.90); }
  75% { -o-transform: scaleX(1.25); }
  100% { -o-transform: scaleX(1.20); }
}
@keyframes ITEMHOVER {
  0% { transform: scaleX(1); }
  25% { transform: scaleX(0.90); }
  75% { transform: scaleX(1.25); }
  100% { transform: scaleX(1.20); }
}

.item:hover {
  -webkit-animation: ITEMHOVER 2s;
  -moz-animation: ITEMHOVER 2s;
  -o-animation: ITEMHOVER 2s;
  animation: ITEMHOVER 2s;
  color: #000000;
}
```

It will work.

NOTE: This was according to your fiddle. In your initial post, you were trying to animate width. Simply changing `itemHover` to `ITEMHOVER` would've done it.